# I have updated targetSdkVersion to Q, But I can not get permission of READ MEDIA IMAGES

Tags: android, android-10.0

I have updated targetSdkVersion to Q, But I can not get new permissions like `READ MEDIA IMAGES`.

This is my build.gradle file:

```
compileSdkVersion 'android-Q'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.targetversiontest"
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 'android-Q'
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
```

I can not get `READ MEDIA IMAGES` using

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGE"/>
```

or

```
Manifest.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGE
```

Anyone know why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They removed that permission in Q Beta 3. Use `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`.

Comment: Why? I have read [google update info](https://developer.android.com/preview/privacy/scoped-storage). Do you have some link of the update?

Comment: @ZhangXu: https://developer.android.com/preview/privacy/scoped-storage (see first starred box)

Comment: Thank you! This has double me a full day! By the way,  Do you know the  `PRIMARY_DIRECTORY ` and `SECONDARY_DIRECTORY ` in `Media` class ？ Are they also obsolete?   And Do you know how to use `ContentValue` and `ContentResolver` to save a image in path of 'DCIM/customFileName/image'?

Comment: @ZhangXu: "Are they also obsolete?" -- I do not know, sorry. "Do you know how to use ContentValue and ContentResolver to save a image in path of 'DCIM/customFileName/image'? " -- see https://developer.android.com/preview/features#storage-location

Comment: now they added this again in Android 13